# Is there a way to access router history from inside an epic aside?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable, epic

I'm using react-router-4 and the corresponding react-router-redux for this version is not yet stable. I'm curious if there are ways I can access `history` from `redux-observable` epic. Example:

```
export function profileDropdownEpic (action$, { getState, dispatch }{
  return action$.ofType('SET_SELECTED_ITEM')
    .mapTo(() => {
      const selectedItem = getState().listDropdown.get('SelectedItem')
      if (selectedItem === 'logout') {
        history.push('/login')
      }  
      return {}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `epics`, you want to include the `History` as a dependency of your `EpicMiddleware`. Dependencies are added as third argument to every epic.

Start out with creating the history.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

When creating the `EpicMiddleware`, pass `history` as argument of the dependency object:

```
createEpicMiddleware({
  dependencies: { 
    history: history
  }
})
```

When creating the actual `Epic`, the third argument contains dependencies, of which one will be `history`.

```
const myEpic = (action, store, dependencies) => {
  // dependency.history.createHref(...)

  return action.pipe(...)
}

combineEpics(myEpic);
```

Comment: Just wondering if this "history" is the same history from React router?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `history.js` file that exports `createHistory()`:

```
// history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
export default createHistory()
```

Then import it in your epic:

```
// epics.js
import history from './history'     

export function profileDropdownEpic (action$, { getState, dispatch }){
  return action$.ofType('SET_SELECTED_ITEM')
    .mapTo(() => {
      const selectedItem = getState().listDropdown.get('SelectedItem')
      if (selectedItem === 'logout') {
        history.push('/login')
      }  
      return {}
  })
}
```

Don't forget to set the history props in your `<Router />`:

```
import history from './history'

<Router history={history}>...</Router>
```